# "StackOverFlowError" building a Tree given 3 nodes with null

Tags: java, binary-tree, stack-overflow

I try to make this tree. To get 3 data and put "." which means "null".

```
      A                                  ex.  A B C                                  
    /   \                                     B D .
   B     C                                    C E F        
  /     / \                                   E . .   
 D     E   F                                  F . G
            \                                 D . .  
             G                                G . .
```

However, I put "."  it makes "java.lang.StackOverflowError" on "next" method.
Here is my Tree Code.

```
class Tree{
    TreeNode root;
    public Tree(char data, char left, char right){
        root = new TreeNode(data);
        if(data != '.')
            root.setData(data);
        if(left != '.')
            root.setLeft(root);
        if(right != '.')
            root.setRight(root);
    }

    public void add(char data, char left, char right){
        next(root.getRight(),data,left,right);
        next(root.getLeft(),data,left,right);

    }

     public void next(TreeNode node, char data, char left, char right){
    if(node.getData() == data){
        if(left != '.'){
            node.setLeft(node);
        }
        if(right != '.'){
            node.setRight(node);
        }
    }
    if(node.getData() == '.'){  ** <= I add the condition "if" **
        next(node.getLeft(),data,left,right);
        next(node.getRight(),data,right,left);
    }
}

public void preOrder(TreeNode node){
        System.out.print(node.getData()); <==== **Now I get the error here**
        if(node.getLeft() != null){
            preOrder(node.getLeft()); <==== **Now I get the error here**
        }
        if(node.getRight() != null){
            preOrder(node.getRight());
        }

    }
```

The tree node class is simple

```
class TreeNode{
    private int data;
    private TreeNode right;
    private TreeNode left;
  .......
 }
```

Could you tell me what is the problem and how can I fix it?
It is too hard to make a normal binary tree.

Here is my errors.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.base/java.nio.ByteBuffer.position(ByteBuffer.java:262)
    at java.base/sun.nio.cs.UTF_8.updatePositions(UTF_8.java:80)
    at java.base/sun.nio.cs.UTF_8$Encoder.encodeArrayLoop(UTF_8.java:509)
    at java.base/sun.nio.cs.UTF_8$Encoder.encodeLoop(UTF_8.java:564)
    at java.base/java.nio.charset.CharsetEncoder.encode(CharsetEncoder.java:578)
    at java.base/sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implWrite(StreamEncoder.java:292)
    at java.base/sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implWrite(StreamEncoder.java:281)
    at java.base/sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.write(StreamEncoder.java:125)
    at java.base/java.io.OutputStreamWriter.write(OutputStreamWriter.java:211)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedWriter.flushBuffer(BufferedWriter.java:120)
    at java.base/java.io.PrintStream.write(PrintStream.java:605)
    at java.base/java.io.PrintStream.print(PrintStream.java:676)
```

Comment: `java.lang.StackOverflowError` could be thrown if your method chain never ends. Is this condition `if(node == null)` in your `next` method ever true? If not, the recursion will go on forever and end up in that exception

Comment: If I deleted if(node == null), It still has the error. The problem is "next(node.getLeft(),data,left,right);
 next(node.getRight(),data,right,left);"        I should make the node point to next position when It is entered "." , I can not make how it points to the next null node.

Comment: In recursion you need a base case that stops the recursion, it is the return statement(s) of the recursive function. In your case, it is when a node has value `.` (null). So you need that line, but also need to verify why it's never true which is the reason why your program never ends and throws the exception. Maybe it's simply `if(node.data == '.')`? Maybe your nodes are not initialized properly? Maybe your recursive call passes wrong parameters? It is easy to spot with a quick debug execution

Comment: I changed and added as you recommended. However, it has the same errors in different partitions. I updated my code on the question.

Comment: Problem is in Tree constructor. You are setting left and right children of root to root itself.